# How can I delete a file from Android's stock "Downloads" app?

Tags: android

From what I [gathered](http://docs.monodroid.net/?link=M%3aAndroid.App.DownloadManager.AddCompletedDownload), it seems that the stock `Downloads` app uses the DownloadManager. I'm trying to remove an entry from the `DownloadManager`'s database as I'm working on an application that cleans the `download` folder.

If I manually remove a file from the `download` folder, it still appears in the `Downloads` app, even though it's not accessible.

What I've tried so far is to query the `DownloadManager` (using DownloadManager.query()) so as to use the `DownloadManager.remove()` function, but the query is not returning any result.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post the code snippet of your DownloadManager.query() call, please?

Comment: Sorry, it was a year ago and I don't have that code anymore.

Comment: Well, do you still need an answer to this? :o)

Comment: Hmm, not really no. I no longer develop that product and I think we changed the feature requirements for that :)